# PHP Cookie

Tags: php, cookie, javascript

Скажите, как сделать на PHP, чтобы в переменную $example поступили данные из javascript - document.cookie?

Comment: Если вам нужно передать печеньки именно из джаваскрипта, то сохраняйте их в строку и кидайте на сервер с помощью аякса.

Answer (score 1):

```
$example = $_COOKIE['cookie_name']
```